# what does static() in django.conf.urls do?

Tags: django

I don't quite understand what it does from the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/urls/#module-django.conf.urls) what this function does and why it is useful.

From the code snippet it provides

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

ALso, what is this MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: to serve static and media files, but only in development.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 0):

1. Its sets the url pattern for user uploaded content and direct the requests to be served from the webserver.
2. MEDIA_URL: Constant for media url defined in the Django settings file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#media-url.
3. MEDIA_ROOT: Constant for media storage root defined in the Django settings file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#media-root.

As noted in comments serving media files from webserver is a security risk and should be avoided.